# Launch JNLP file on Ubuntu/Linux in Browser(Chrome(67) /Mozilla)

Tags: javascript, java, linux, ubuntu, jnlp

JNLP is not getting launched on click of a button in Ubuntu OS. I don't have any issue on Windows

Here is how I launch :

```
  dtjava.launch({
        url : "<JNLP file URL>"
    }, {
        javafx : '8.0+'
    }, {});
```

The same code is working on windows, but I have faced the problem in Linux.

Here is URL where I found the above code from :

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/deployment_toolkit.html

Am I missing something to launch it in Ubuntu? Could anyone please help me?

Comment: I'd be surprised if any browser will still launch JWS apps. See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/moving-to-a-plugin-free-web).

Comment: Thanks. Any alternative solution or plugin? Any link that could help me on plugin free web ?

Comment: *"Any alternative solution.."* A pure web app. with JS for the heavy lifting? An installer for the Java app.? I have no idea. What's it do? What functionality does it provide?